# malformed header being generated

Tags: windows, apache, perl, dhtml

I'm working on a windows 10/Apache/dHTML (Perl) platform trying to upload an .HTML file.   I have a form that allows me to browse to select the file I want to upload.  The form line follows.

```
<FORM encTYPE='multipart/FORM-data' ACTION='uploadx.cgi' NAME='ManMe' METHOD='POST' ONSUBMIT='return reqchk()'>\n";
```

I'm getting the correct path and file to upload and destination path and file in uploadx.cgi as shown next as comments.   The actual upload code follows.

```
# comment - $upload_filehandle is C:\usr\www\kyhealth.html - correct input location            
      $upload_filehandle = $page->upload("filex"); # File handle to uploaded file.

# comment - $thefn C:/Steep/USAData/State/KY/Ideals/Health/kyhealth.html - correct output location
      open(my $UF_fh,'>',$thefn) || croak "Couldn't open file $filex, $!";      

      if (index(lc($thefn),'.gif') > -1) {
        binmode($UF_fh); # Set file output to binary mode if image.
      }       

      while ( <$upload_filehandle> )  {      
        print $UF_fh; # Write it out.
      }

      close $UF_fh;
```

The errors in the Apache log file from the execution of uploaddx.cgi follow.

[Wed Jun 23 15:16:44.349636 2021] [core:error] [pid 9772:tid 1056] [client 192.253.246.153:62520] malformed header from script 'uploadx.cgi': Bad header: , referer: [http://steepusa.no-ip.info/scx/cmf2mme.cgi?strmme=SKY_458~422~438~428~430~382_326~366~438~458~450~392_U_level3_326~366~438~458~450~392](http://steepusa.no-ip.info/scx/cmf2mme.cgi?strmme=SKY_458%7E422%7E438%7E428%7E430%7E382_326%7E366%7E438%7E458%7E450%7E392_U_level3_326%7E366%7E438%7E458%7E450%7E392)
[Wed Jun 23 15:16:44.349636 2021] [perl:warn] [pid 9772:tid 1056] /scx/uploadx.cgi did not send an HTTP header

The output file is created with the right name in the right place.  But the file has zero bytes.
there is no 'Content-type:  text/html' header in the uploadx.cgi file.  It just tries to upload
the file and put it in new file in a particular directory as shown above.  And the 'Bad Header:' is not telling me much.

I have looked at quite a few posts here and elsewhere about similar problems with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not sure how to move the ball on this one.   Thanks.

ct

Comment: ikegami,  I didn't know I needed to send a header.   So I am confused about why I'm getting the error.   At the end o the update, I call a small routine as follows.

Comment: ```sub getback1 {

  my $appbgcolr = shift;

  print "Content-type:  text/html\n\n";

  print "<HTML><BODY STYLE='BACKGROUND-COLOR:#$appbgcolr;'>\n";

  print "<SCRIPT TYPE='text/JavaScript'>

    window.alert('The file has been uploaded.   Verify\\r\\nthe upload in the user interface.');
    window.history.go(-1);

  </SCRIPT>\n";

  print "</BODY></HTML>\n";

  return;

}
```

Comment: Can this be the problem?  I didn't think so.   I don't know.

Comment: I thought maybe that was the header it was barking at.   It generates the message but does not color the background until I respond to the alert.    I'm confused on this.

Comment: The updatex process is the backend to the initial selection form and returns to that form after the alert message at the very end of updatex.

Comment: I eliminated the above header and it still generated the same 2 errors in the Apache log file.

Comment: As I said, I did not think I needed to send a header for this 'backend upload work.  That is why I don't understand these error messages.

Comment: Sir I wish I understood what your asking me.    Provide a response to what request?    Please helpme understand.   There are no conetnt headers coded in the uploadx process

Comment: except that routine called at the very end of the process.   Thats why I'm confused by the error messages.

Comment: The alert in the sub occurs.   The alert message 'The file has been uploaded.   Verify the upload in the user interface.' pops up and when I press the OK button. I return to the selection form.   But the background behind the alert is not the color its supposed to be.  And when I OK the alert, it passes quickly through that background on the screen with alot of GLOB messages quickly shown before the selection form appears.

Answer (score 0):

The first message follows from the first. The header emitted by the script is malformed in the sense that not emitting any header at all is a malformed header/response.

> There are no conetnt headers coded in the uploadx process

HTTP requests must result in a response. You seem to be claiming that you do not send a response, which would result in exactly this kind of error. When you use a CGI script, the onus falls on the script to produce this response. If you don't, the server will typically send a 500 error response and log a message such as the one you asked about.

Keep in mind that a common reason for a script not sending a header is because it died (from a compile-time or run-time error) before it got a chance to do so. A situation such as this one should have left an earlier message in the log file.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by an http request and a response please?  And thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: When I inspect hte process when the alert occurs, I see the following.

Comment: In the DOM, I see the body tag followed by GLOB(0x27faa7560f0) several hundred times followed by the content header and the rest of the subroutine.  In the debugger, I get  GLOB(0x27faa7560f0) several hundred times followed by the sub down down to the opening bracket.

Comment: HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
uploadx.cgi
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
uploadx.cgi (1,4096)
HTML1513: Extra "<html>" tag found. Only one "<html>" tag should exist per document.
uploadx.cgi (3,1)
HTML1503: Unexpected start tag.
uploadx.cgi (3,7)
HTML1512: Unmatched end tag.
uploadx.cgi (3,13)
HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.
uploadx.cgi (3,20)

Comment: I got the above warnings in the console.   I don't see any  of this in the debugger code.

Comment: And I had not seen the warnings before, but I may have missed them because no errors were flagged in the console.  So I may have missed them.

Comment: If you question needs clarification, fix it.

Comment: I think what you mean by http rrequest is the client request that comes from my selection form.   I wonder if my server response time to that request is too slow?

Comment: I'm doing this work on my Apache server.    My server is acting as both client and server.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I'm experiencing significant degradation of ping, download and upload speeds.   My upload speed was actually zero when I just did a speedtest with my provider.  My telecommunications provider has opened a ticket.  This is the first time I've encountered this situation.   Thanks ikegami.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from a hotspot internet connection to a router and that solved the malformed header problem.    All upload tests were successful with the router connection.